# I'm trying to get information in an HTML message

Tags: javascript, html, cheerio

in the head part within the html, there are 4 pieces of information that I wanted to get using cheerio, but I tried everything and it is always returning an invalid value, in this case returning NOTHING
in the javascript code it has the 4 options that I am trying to get from the html, if possible someone can help I would appreciate it
[image]

my code

```
    const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const headers = {
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=0cpr6cn0mdqhab6v6vvdi0ifbm',
    'Host': 'sistemas.viareal.net',
    'Origin': 'https://sistemas.viareal.net',
    'Referer': 'https://sistemas.viareal.net/utp-dev/index.php?ti=pl',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
};

const minhaFuncaoAssincrona = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('https://sistemas.viareal.net/utp-dev/index.php?s=pl', {
            cep: '93285310',
            numcasa: '85'
        }, { headers, timeout: 160000 });

        const extrairInformacoes = (html) => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);

            const viabilidade = $('font:contains("Rede disponível no endereço pesquisado")').length > 0;

            if (viabilidade) {
                console.log('Há viabilidade no endereço pesquisado.');

                const enderecoProspectado = $('td:contains("Endereço prospectado:")').next().find('b').text().trim();
                const ctoPreferencial = $('b:contains("CTO Preferencial:")').closest('td').next().text().trim();
                const ctoAlternativa1 = $('b:contains("CTO Alternativa 1:")').closest('td').next().text().trim();
                const ctoAlternativa2 = $('b:contains("CTO Alternativa 2:")').closest('td').next().text().trim();

                console.log('Endereço Prospectado:', enderecoProspectado);
                console.log('CTO Preferencial:', ctoPreferencial);
                console.log('CTO Alternativa 1:', ctoAlternativa1);
                console.log('CTO Alternativa 2:', ctoAlternativa2);

            } else {
                console.log('Não há viabilidade no endereço pesquisado.');
            }
        };

        extrairInformacoes(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro na solicitação:', error.message);
    }
};

minhaFuncaoAssincrona();
```

html response

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>   <head>      <link rel='SHORTCUT ICON' href='knife.png'/>        <style>            /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */            #map {                height: 500px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */                width: 700px;  /* The width is the width of the web page */            }        .blink {
    animation: blinker 0.8s linear infinite;
    color: #cc0000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
@keyframes blinker {
    0% {
    opacity: 0;
   }
}        </style>       <Title>UTP - Pinga Lote</title><style type="text/css">
body {color: #737373; font-size: 10px; font-family: verdana;}

textarea,input,select {
background-color: #FDFBFB;
border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
padding: 2px;
margin: 1px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #808080;
}

a, a:link, a:visited, a:active { color: #1212FF; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; }
a:hover { border-bottom: 1px dotted #c1c1c1; color: #AAAAAA; }
img {border: none;}
td { font-size: 14px; color: #7A7A7A; }
</style>


</head>    <body><table border=0 width=100%><tr><td><center><table border=0 bgcolor=#eeeeee width=100%><tr><td valign=center colspan=14 bgcolor=#FF0D5D><font color=white><center>UTP - Versão 0.23 - Bem vindo FVARGAS.SPEEDFOX@VEROPAR.COM.BR. <a href=index.php?s=logout><font color=white>Deslogar.</a></td></tr><tr><td height=80 valign=center width=200><center><a href=index.php?ti=pl><img src=pingalote.png><br><font face='Arial' color='black' size='2'>Pinga Lote</a></td><td height=80 valign=center width=200><center><a href=index.php?s=ctoProx><img src=ctoprox.png><br><font face='Arial' color='black' size='2'>CTO Próxima</a></td><td height=80 valign=center width=200><center><a href=index.php?ti=ts><img src=timesheet.png><br><font face='Arial' color='black' size='2'>TimeSheet</a></td><td height=80 valign=center width=200><center><a href=index.php?s=valid1><img src=valida.png><br><font face='Arial' color='black' size='2'>Valida CTO</a></td></td></tr></table>        <style>            /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */            #map {                height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */                width: 600px;  /* The width is the width of the web page */            }        </style><center><table border=0 bgcolor=#eeeeee width=100%><tr><td colspan=2 bgcolor=#FF0D5D><font color=white><center>Informações de Viabilidade</td><tr><td valign=top><center><center><table border=0 bgcolor=#eeeeee><tr><td bgcolor=#cccccc><center><font face='arial' color='black' size='2'>Dados da pesquisa</td></tr><tr><td><br><font face='arial' color='black' size='2'>Endereço prospectado:<br> <b>Rua Bandeirantes, 85 Liberdade Esteio/RS</b> <br><br><font color=green><b><center>Rede disponível no endereço pesquisado<br><br></b></font><b>CTO Preferencial:</b> [EIO-024-2-2/C:16/O:0/D:16]<b> GPON</b> FTTH <br><font color=black>Distância em linha reta: 44 m  <font color=black> <font color=black>Pelo arruamento: 37 m <font color=black><br>R. Bandeirantes, 48 - Liberdade, Esteio - RS, 93285-310, Brazil<br><br><b>CTO Alternativa 1:</b> [EIO-024-2-3/C:16/O:0/D:16]<b> GPON</b>  FTTH <br><font color=black>Distância em linha reta: 74 m   <font color=black> <font color=black>Pelo arruamento: 206 m  <font color=black><br>Rua 7 de Setembro, 122 - Liberdade, Esteio - RS, 93285-280, Brazil<br><br><b>CTO Alternativa 2:</b> [EIO-024-2-4/C:16/O:0/D:16]<b> GPON</b>  FTTH <br><font color=black>Distância em linha reta: 119 m   <font color=black> <font color=black>Pelo arruamento: 191 m  <font color=black><br>R. Império, 245 - Liberdade, Esteio - RS, 93285-300, Brazil<br><br><a href=index.php?s=pl&oc=true&lat=-29.8570493&lng=-51.1626037>Fazer essa pesquisa novamente considerando ocupação de portas.</a></td></tr></table></td><td width=60%>    <!--The div element for the map -->    <div id='map'></div>    <script>        function initMap() {var prospect = {lat: -29.8570493, lng: -51.1626037};
var ctoProx = {lat: -29.85685456114, lng: -51.16300520971};
var ctoProx2 = {lat: -29.85759455392, lng: -51.16303747274};
var ctoProx3 = {lat: -29.85617002886, lng: -51.16190663742};
var ctoProx4 = {lat: -29.85797213144, lng: -51.16421839478};
var ctoProx5 = {lat: -29.85522027068, lng: -51.16365481213};
var cto = {lat: -29.76780141496, lng: -51.15253019817};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 17, center: prospect, mapTypeId: 'hybrid', styles:  [
{
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#ebe3cd"
}
]
},
{
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#523735"
}
]
},
{
"elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#f5f1e6"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "administrative",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
{
"visibility": "off"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "administrative",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#c9b2a6"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#dcd2be"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#ae9e90"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "landscape.natural",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#dfd2ae"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "poi",
"stylers": [
{
"visibility": "off"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "poi",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#dfd2ae"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "poi",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#93817c"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "poi.park",
"elementType": "geometry.fill",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#a5b076"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "poi.park",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#447530"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "road",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#f5f1e6"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "road",
"elementType": "labels.icon",
"stylers": [
{
"visibility": "off"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "road.arterial",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#fdfcf8"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "road.highway",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#f8c967"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "road.highway",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#e9bc62"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#e98d58"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#db8555"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "road.local",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#806b63"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "transit",
"stylers": [
{
"visibility": "off"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "transit.line",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#dfd2ae"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "transit.line",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#8f7d77"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "transit.line",
"elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#ebe3cd"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "transit.station",
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#dfd2ae"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "water",
"elementType": "geometry.fill",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#b9d3c2"
}
]
},
{
"featureType": "water",
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
{
"color": "#92998d"
}
]
}
]
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '', position: prospect});var prospectIcon = {  url: 'pin18-yellow.png',labelOrigin:  new google.maps.Point(9, -2), size: new google.maps.Size(18, 26),origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 26)};
var ctopIcon = {  url: 'selecionado.png',labelOrigin:  new google.maps.Point(0, -4), size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 20)};
var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({position: prospect, map: map, label: 'Cliente', draggable:true, icon: prospectIcon});
function handleEvent(event) {
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({position: event.latLng});
var NovoP = '<a href=index.php?s=pl&latP=' +  event.latLng.lat() + '&lngP=' +  event.latLng.lng() + '>Nova busca aqui</a>';                                 
infoWindow.setContent(NovoP);
infoWindow.open(map);
}marker0.addListener('dragend', handleEvent);var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position: ctoProx, map: map, icon: ctopIcon, label: 'CTO Preferencial[16/16]'});
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: ctoProx2, map: map, icon: ctopIcon, label: 'CTO Alternativa 1[16/16]'});
var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({position: ctoProx3, map: map, icon: ctopIcon, label: 'CTO Alternativa 2[16/16]'});
var cto = {lat: -29.85685456114, lng: -51.16300520971};
var ctoCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                  strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                  strokeOpacity: 0.2,
                  strokeWeight: 0.2,
                  fillColor: '#FF0000',
                  fillOpacity: 0.25,
                  map: map,
                  center: cto,
                  radius: 150,
                  zIndex: 5
              });
var cto = {lat: -29.85759455392, lng: -51.16303747274};
var ctoCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                  strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                  strokeOpacity: 0.2,
                  strokeWeight: 0.2,
                  fillColor: '#FF0000',
                  fillOpacity: 0.25,
                  map: map,
                  center: cto,
                  radius: 150,
                  zIndex: 5
              });
var cto = {lat: -29.85617002886, lng: -51.16190663742};
var ctoCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                  strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                  strokeOpacity: 0.2,
                  strokeWeight: 0.2,
                  fillColor: '#FF0000',
                  fillOpacity: 0.25,
                  map: map,
                  center: cto,
                  radius: 150,
                  zIndex: 5
              });
}
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD-D6oUG0QtWftzZ6ZOLfcKA6_zz3kQjhs&callback=initMap&libraries=visualization">        </script></td></tr></table>    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since many of us can't read the text, it would be useful if you could indicate what you expect the results to be for the four queries and the html response you included.